# Is there any performance improvement for NOT using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm completing a relatively straightforward project that needs a tiny amount of Javascript, but speed is also important.

I'm used to doing everything with jQuery, but, in a case like this, is there any chance this will slow it down? I imagine that needing to load up an additional JS file will cause a little delay, but after this, during the running of the page, are there likely to be any noticeable delays?

Comment: It'll really depend on what you're going to do exactly. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization, without knowing what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery will take a performance hit over pure JavaScript, naturally, this has always been the case, but never noticeable unless you're misusing it.

The question that you have to ask yourself, with your "tiny amount of JavaScript", can you afford to write it without thinking if it'll work in all browsers? This is exactly why people take the menial performance hit when using jQuery.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say `never noticeable`

Comment: It'll depend on the use/misuse by the developer, as with any language wrappers really.